# How to define transparent element in colormap

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, colormap

I would like to define a transparent color within the color map how do I do that?

The reason I need this is that I have a multiple layers in my `axes` (produced both by `imagesc` and `plot`). I know I could simply first use `imagesc` and then `plot` but I want to draw the lines behind non-zero values of the `imagesc` representation.

To color the zeros white I use

```
jet = colormap('jet');
jet(1:2,:) = 1;
colormap(jet);
```

Now I would like to make white transparent.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The `colormap` doesn't have a fourth element for alpha, it's RGB only, so the way I do this sort of thing is to make a mask of the desired transparency layer - binary or greyscale will work - and then apply that to the image. To do this you need to store the handle of the image

```
% make random image
im = rand(100,100);
% make example alphamask
alphamask = im<0.3;
% store handle
hnd = imagesc(im);
% apply mask
set(hnd, 'AlphaData', alphamask);
```

Comment: Nice answer. I was just writing the same :-)

Comment: Very nice, thank you. Now I only have to figure out how to export this nice figure into a `pdf`, because `export_fig` doesn't support `alpha` as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks @LuisMendo : ) It's the best way!

Comment: @magu_ I just export to png, I think you might have to use an external tool to convert to pdf (if you're on linux `convert` should do the job: http://askubuntu.com/questions/158093/how-do-i-convert-a-png-to-pdf-with-only-the-default-packages-on-11-10)

Comment: I'm on linux, but my typical workflow normally looks like this: matlab figure saved as pdf -> Inkscape saved as pdf + latex -> import it into latex. But maybe should think about simplifying this process anyway.

Comment: I always used to use eps for my latex workflow but I never had to use images there let alone transparency! You could embed the `convert` call inside your matlab script using `system`?